# Using a subselect for ST_Distance query

Tags: postgis, query, postgresql-9.6

So I am at a bit of a loss here, trying to get the distance in meters between a point stored in my table and a set of coordinates

```
locations

id    |   name  |    location(point)
-------------------------------
1        church     (52.632466,4.743884)
```

I'm using the following query for this

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
        ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText((select location from locations where id = 1) , 4326),2163),
        ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)', 4326),2163)
    );
```

And all I get is an error that the function does not exist, I have tested the function from the example on the documentation and that does work.

```
ERROR:  function st_geomfromtext(point, integer) does not exist
LINE 2:    ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText((select location from locati...
                    ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need 
to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 37
```

Any help in the right direction would be great.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175834/distance-in-meters-between-two-geographic-coordinates
take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText((select location from locations where id = 1) , 4326),2163)
```

You are selecting a **point geometry** from a table, but then you are claiming it is not a point, but text (wrapped in st_geomfromtext).

So just change it to:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
    ST_Transform((select location from locations where id = 1), 2163),
    ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)', 4326),2163)
);
```

Alternatively you could select the geometry as text:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
        ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText((select ST_AsText(location) from locations where id = 1)),2163),
        ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)', 4326),2163)
    );
```

If you have used the PostgreSQL native point type:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
        ST_Transform((select st_setsrid(ST_MakePoint(location[0],location[1]), 4326) from locations where id = 1),2163),
        ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)', 4326),2163)
    );
```

And since your geometries are in completely different parts of the world, measuring in geography makes a lot more sense.

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
        ((select st_setsrid(ST_MakePoint(location[0],location[1]), 4326) from locations where id = 1))::geography,
        (ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)', 4326))::geography, True
    );
```

Comment: Tried your first solution, that returns the following error
`ERROR:  function st_transform(point, integer) does not exist
LINE 2:    ST_Transform((select location from locations where id = 1...`

Your second suggestion also nets me an error, also about a non-existing function. Could it be I am missing a postGIS extension?

Comment: What are the results of SELECT PostGIS_full_version()

Comment: that would be:
`POSTGIS="2.3.0 r15146" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 4392" PROJ="Rel. 5.2.0, September 1st, 2018" GDAL="GDAL 2.4.0dev, released 2018/99/99" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.12.1" TOPOLOGY RASTER`

Comment: And try: SELECT ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)', 4326),2163)

Comment: returns a geometry value 010200002073080000020000009B2B3C84380841418ADCDDADDC58F9406A595C20C51D41410EA3F18DE0AEF140

Comment: How did create the locations dataset? I think you might have used the PostgreSQL Point type instead of the PostGIS Geometry type. I will update the query to try.

Comment: I did use the point type, and i have tried your query, yet another error `ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "0101000020E61000007D" <-- parse error at position 20 within geometry
SQL state: XX000`

Comment: Yeah, you should be using Geometry instead of point if you want to use PostGIS functions. What do you get with: select location[0], location[1] from locations where id = 1

Comment: that separated the lat and lon into double precision values

Comment: And is it lat lon or lon lat? What are the numbers?

Comment: Ahhh.. I get the issue, you are trying the measure the distance between a point in the Netherlands, and a line in America in a US National Atlas Equal Area projection. This will not work. I will add a final query.

Comment: That worked. 
The distance is a little bit off, but I know there are ways to fix that. My main issue then was my improper use of data types, in your last query did you parse the 2 points to geometry?

Comment: With the point it is parsed into geometry, then cast into geography. With the line it is just cast into geography. I have update the final query to use a spheroid rather than a sphere, which should be slower but more accurate.

Comment: it still shows up as 12000 KM, which should be more like 5000, also on a smaller scale 44 KM it still deviates by 10 KM

Comment: Switch it to: location[1],location[0]

Comment: that worked on the long distance one but on the 44 KM it becomes completely incorrect

Comment: Your coordinates are then in the wrong order.

Comment: ah, i had both in the wrong order now i see